# ClassNotFoundException using QuarkusClassLoader with local class and Debezium Engine

Tags: java, classloader, quarkus, debezium

```
ClassLoader classLoader = QuarkusClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
String str = "com.mycompany.service.SomeClass";
try {
  Class<? extends SomeClass> someClass =
      (Class<? extends SomeClass>) classLoader.loadClass(str);
} catch (Throwable e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I'm trying to figure out why I get `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException` when I try to load `com.mycompany.service.SomeClass`. This class is defined locally in the project, I'm getting this error when I start my Quarkus app (mvn compile quarkus:dev). If I use another class loader (i.e. this.getClass().getClassLoader()), this error does not happen. It seems like it only happens with QuarkusClassLoader

EDIT:
I think in the end the problem was related to Debezium Engine initialisation. That exception was thrown when calling the following line:

```
// Create the engine with this configuration ...
engine =
    DebeziumEngine.create(Json.class)
        .using(props)
        .notifying(this::handleDbChangeEvent)
        .build();
```

See my answer for how I fixed it

Comment: Can you try using `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()` as the classloader?

Comment: Yep with that one it will work but I'm trying to figure out why it doesn't with QuarkusClassLoader. Mostly because where this is called is not code that I own, I just managed to reproduce that error that way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by passing `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()` in the engine initialisation.

```
engine =
    DebeziumEngine.create(Json.class)
        // Have to pass the current class loader to avoid ClassNotFoundException
        .using(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader())
        .using(props)
        .notifying(this::handleDbChangeEvent)
        .build();
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `Classloader.getSystemClassLoader` is certainly not the correct thing to do because in dev-mode (and more generally, you would rarely want to do that in Java code), Quarkus dot not a flat classloader structure, but a layered one.

See https://quarkus.io/guides/class-loading-reference for more details on how Classloading in dev-mode works.

You can force all classes of a jar to be loaded by the system ClassLoader instead of the Quarkus ClassLoader by using something like:

quarkus.class-loading.parent-first-artifacts=stax:stax-api

Where you essentially configure the groupId and the artifactId of the jar that should be loaded by the system ClassLoader

Comment: Afraid I don't really understand what this means. Is there a way to force a class to be available in dev mode?

Comment: Thanks for your updated answer, unfortunately this did not work either (I tried with a different groupId:artifactId of course). See my answer for what worked